# How to update a number on a website with PHP from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a website which gets MySQL data with PHP. Now, I want to let it update automatically every x seconds. The problem is, that using a while loop with sleep() the website won't load. **How can I update a number on a website with PHP?**

I tried to do it with JavaScript/jQuery, but it didn't work:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("updating");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

test.php (example, MySQL implementation later):

```
<?php
    echo("1.0");
?>
```

It shows only "success", but no number is printed. **What do I need to change without chaning that much of the code?**

The speed etc. does not really matter, because it's just a website with low traffic.

Comment: you need SSE or a WebSocket for that, if you have only a number i suggest you use only js

Comment: Firstly is the AJAX request you've got working? Secondly, to increase a number you need to actually store it somewhere, like a database or in the session. Just having a plain old PHP variable won't work as it's stateless and won't be stored between requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got success alert because, you just only put a string "success" in your alert. change this **alert('success');** to **alert(data);** to test what is the response from your **test.php**

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("updating");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

This code show's how to increment the number and save it depends on your query.

Javascript

```
var number = 0;
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("updating");
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: 'test.php',
      data:'number=' + number;
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        number = data;
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

test.php

```
<?php 
  echo intval($_POST['number']) + 1;
 ?>
```

Comment: Yeah i know, but he said **It shows only "success", but no number is printed. What do I need to change without chaning that much of the code? **. i just want to tell him that he got the string because he just put the success string inside the alert.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question , If you want to update without a database then you can try this way, Hope it helps
Javascript

```
var count=0;
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("updating");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      type:'post',
      data:{count:count},
      success: function(data) {
        count = parseInt(data)+1;
        alert(count);
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

In test.php

```
<?php
    echo($_POST['count']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, how are you getting the number? Assuming it is from your database and you just want to get the latest or updated data number there.

With ajax:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("updating");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
        $('#the_number').html(data);; //the responsed number from database
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

PHP / html file

```
<div id="the_number"><?php echo $the_number ?></div>
```